# Node.JS middleware login

Tags: node.js, authentication, middleware

I'm building a node + express app, and i need to pass the login data in every route, like this:

```
app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
        res.render('dashboard/dashboard', { user: req.user });
});
```

There's a way to always pass req.user as user to the view? (I'm using EJS btw)

I already have a middleware to check if the user is logged, or he will be redirected to login.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [app.use](http://expressjs.com/ru/api.html#app.use) method

```
app.use(isLoggedIn);
```

Then:

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard/dashboard', { user: req.user });
});
```